# agvtool is reporting “Cannot find Foo.xcodeproj/../NO”

Tags: xcode, agvtool

I use [`agvtool`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1827/_index.html) to bump my build numbers. In my recently refactored Xcode 13.0 (13A233) project, but am getting a strange error:

> Cannot find "Foo.xcodeproj/../NO"

E.g.

```
% agvtool next-version -all                          
Setting version of project Foo to: 
    108.

Also setting CFBundleVersion key (assuming it exists)

Updating CFBundleVersion in Info.plist(s)...

Updated CFBundleVersion in "Foo.xcodeproj/../Foo/Support files/Environments/QA/Info.plist" to 108
Updated CFBundleVersion in "Foo.xcodeproj/../FooKit/Info.plist" to 108
Updated CFBundleVersion in "Foo.xcodeproj/../FooTests/Info.plist" to 108
Cannot find "Foo.xcodeproj/../NO"
```

I only have those three targets, `Foo`, `FooKit`, and `FooTests`, but it is looking for another one called `NO`.

I have looked around and do not see any extraneous `Info.plist` files. I am guessing that there is something set to `NO` in `.pbxproj` or `Info.plist` which `agvtool` is incorrectly picking up as a potential target, but I have not figured where it is. How precisely does the `-all` option figure out which `Info.plist` files need updating?

Comment: Hello @Rob Could you please explain a bit the exact solution of the issue.

Comment: I have added the particulars below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My work-around was to set the “Bundle version” in my various `Info.plist` files to `$(CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION)`:

[image]

Then I don't need to use the `-all` optional at all. I simply:

```
% agvtool next-version                                                                  
Setting version of project Foo to: 
    126.
```

The `.plist` files will grab the version from the target, rather than being specified individually in the respective files. This avoids the curious behavior/bug of the `-all` option.